# How to uninstall OCaml in mac?

Tags: ocaml

I have the ocaml functionality in my mac (I'm using Sierra).I did not use opam or macport to install them.So how do I uninstall OCaml from my system?
I've been searching on Google but I can barely found one that discuss about how to do it in mac.I hope someone can explain this clearly..Thank you very much!!

Comment: Doesn't `brew uninstall ocaml` work in your terminal?

Comment: @Lhooq i got this error : brew: command not found

Comment: What does `which -a ocaml` says?

Comment: Look at the install script you used, and see where it put the files.  Then delete them.  I don't believe that ocaml would have config info in obscure files that require wizardry to find, as some full-fledged MacOS apps do.  If you used the `make` command, run it as `make -n`.  The -n says: show me what you would do, but don't do it.

Comment: What I meant was, if part of the installation process involved running `make install`, go back to the directory from which you ran it, but run `make -n install`.  That will tell you where the files were placed.